# Disabling specific option within Struts.html tag options tag

Tags: html, jsp, struts1

I have a JSP wherein a dropdown option implements as:

```
<html:select property="ComplayDetail">
<html:options collection="companyList" name="companyAttribute" property="attribute" />
</html:select>
```

This drop-down option has values dynamically added like ABC,CDE, DEF,EfG.... 
Now i want to make an option i.e. DEF disable.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: What does "disable" mean? What html code do you want?

Comment: By disable i mean a specific value cannot be selected. For example DEF as a values should not be selected in above list.

Comment: `<option value="DEF" disabled>DEF</option>`?

Comment: No, actually this value is dynamically added by given snippet:

<html:options collection="companyList" name="companyAttribute" property="attribute" />

Comment: You may have to use <html:option> with logic tag libraries instead of <html:options> because <html:options> does not have disabled attribute.

Comment: you can handle this using javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

i think for jquery like :

```
$("#selectId > option").each(function() {

var currentvalue=$(this).val();

if(currentvalue == "DEF")
    {
       this.disabled=true;
    }

});
```

Comment: i Will try this